# How to control event propagation in directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a 'CloseHandlerDirective' which handles the closing of modals and dropdowns when clicked anywhere outside the event target or when pressing escape.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit, Output, EventEmitter, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[closeHandler]'
})
export class CloseHandlerDirective implements AfterContentInit {
    @Output() closeHandler: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();
    private _visible: boolean = false;
    private _globalClickUnregister: Function;
    private _globalKeyDownUnregister: Function;
    private _elementClickUnregister: Function;

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this._render = this._render.bind(this);
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this._elementClickUnregister = this.renderer.listen(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', this._render);
    }

    _render(event: Event): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this._visible = !this._visible;

        if (this._visible) {
            // Emits a close event, if it detects a click outside of the native Element
            this._globalClickUnregister = this.renderer
                .listenGlobal('document', 'click', (clickEvent: Event) => {
                const CLICKED_INSIDE: Boolean = this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement
                                                    .contains(clickEvent.target);
                if (!CLICKED_INSIDE) {
                    this.closeHandler.emit(null);
                    this._visible = false;
                    this._globalClickUnregister();
                    if(this._globalKeyDownUnregister) {
                        this._globalKeyDownUnregister();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Emits a close event, if it detects that "Escape" was pressed
            this._globalKeyDownUnregister = this.renderer
                .listenGlobal('document', 'keydown', (keyDownEvent: KeyboardEvent) => {
                    let key: String = keyDownEvent.key;
                    if (key === 'Escape' || key === 'Esc') {
                        this.closeHandler.emit(null);
                        this._visible = false;
                        this._globalKeyDownUnregister();
                        if(this._globalClickUnregister) {
                            this._globalClickUnregister();
                        }
                    }
                });
        } else {
            if (this._globalClickUnregister) {
                this._globalClickUnregister();
            }
            if(this._globalKeyDownUnregister) {
                this._globalKeyDownUnregister();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works beautifully except for one thing:
I have a dropdown which is inside a table row. The whole table row has a routerLink on it. I have `event.stopPropagation();` as the first thing in my EventListener, so that the event doesn't bubble up to the routerLink. Otherwise the dropdown wouldn't show and it would go straight to the page the router points to.
But this also means that when I have more than one dropdown per page and I open the first dropdown and open another one, the first one doesn't close, because it doesn't register as a "outside click" because of the `event.stopPropagation();`.

How can I fix this so that only one instance of my dropdown component at a time is allowed to be open?